# PowerShell Select-String matches nothing despite trying everything in TFM

Tags: powershell

Every time I drop into PowerShell it's always the same.  Some random hieroglyphics that never work as expected.  This time I'm trying to filter the output of Get-WindowsFeature to display all lines containing TIFF (so the PS equivalent of `| grep TIFF` or `| find /i "TIFF"`).  This is what I've tried so far, and the output (empty in all cases), and I have of course RTFM.  The first few lines show the end of the output of Get-WindowsFeature so there is definitely at least one matching line (6th from the end):

```
Display Name                                   Name                    Install State
------------                                   ----                    -------------
[ ] Windows Search Service                     Search-Service          Available
[ ] Windows Server Backup                      Windows-Server-Backup   Available
[ ] Windows Server Migration Tools             Migration               Available
[ ] Windows Standards-Based Storage Management WindowsStorageManage... Available
[ ] Windows TIFF IFilter                       Windows-TIFF-IFilter    Available
[ ] WinRM IIS Extension                        WinRM-IIS-Ext           Available
[ ] WINS Server                                WINS                    Available
[ ] Wireless LAN Service                       Wireless-Networking     Available
[X] WoW64 Support                              WoW64-Support           Installed
[ ] XPS Viewer                                 XPS-Viewer              Available


PS C:\Windows\system32> get-windowsfeature | select-string "TIFF"
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-windowsfeature | select-string TIFF
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-windowsfeature | select-string 'TIFF'
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-windowsfeature | select-string -Pattern 'TIFF'
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-windowsfeature | select-string -Pattern 'TIFF' -AllMatches
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-windowsfeature | select-string -Pattern "TIFF"
PS C:\Windows\system32> get-windowsfeature | select-string -Pattern TIFF
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature | Select-String -Pattern TIFF
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature | Select-String -Pattern 'TIFF'
PS C:\Windows\system32> $A = Get-WindowsFeature | Select-String -Pattern 'TIFF'
PS C:\Windows\system32> $A
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature | Select-String -Pattern 'TIFF' -SimpleMatch
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'TIFF'
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature |& Select-String -SimpleMatch 'TIFF'
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'TIFF' 2>&1
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature 2>&1 | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'TIFF'
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature 3>&1 | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'TIFF'
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

To solve my problem this time I gave up and redirected the output to a file, and used Notepad to find it.  But for next time I'd still like to know what random set of characters is needed to make this thing work.

For extra clarification, here's an expected output mockup:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-WindowsFeature | Select-String <what exactly goes here?>
[ ] Windows TIFF IFilter                                Windows-TIFF-IFilter           Available

PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: `get-windowsfeature | ? {$_.Name -match 'TIFF'}`

Comment: Most likely you got tripped up because `get-windowsfeature` (and most/any other command) outputs a stream of strings to the console so you are mistakingly assuming you can grep/search on that. That's not how powershell works. It outputs objects on wich you can operate. My 'goto' for finding out applied to your case is to dump all properties like this `get-windowsfeature[0] | fl *`. After that I look at the properties of interest and work from there.

Comment: If you rather use strings as output, this would work `(get-windowsfeature | Out-String) -split "`r`n" | sls TIFF`. Performance wise not noticable in this case but I wouldn't use it anywhere in production. The gist of this is to effectively turn the output to *one* string whereafter you have to split it into multiple lines before select-string can select only those lines containing TIFF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited the headers back in.  I thought this might have been some kind of strange custom format like get-date.  Anyway, the usual way to filter a property in powershell is like this.  It's sort of like sql.  This is a server only command:

```
get-windowsfeature | where displayname -match tiff
get-windowsfeature | where name -match tiff
get-windowsfeature | where installstate -eq installed
```

It's not great that the header slightly differs from the property name here.

It's not a bad idea to keep findstr in your toolbox for situations like this.  Note that findstr is normally case sensitive without the '/i' option:

```
get-windowsfeature | findstr TIFF
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you misunderstood the command `Select-String`.

As described in the docs of `Select-String`:

> Finds text in strings and files.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string?view=powershell-7

Your Get-WindowsFeature is neither a string or a file. It's mostly some kind of object like most other commands in powershell. You can easily check with:

```
(Get-WindowsFeature).getType()
```

I don't have a Windows Server ready to test but we can also take another command like `Get-Alias`

```
(Get-Alias).getType()
```

Output:

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name      BaseType
-------- -------- ----      --------
True     True     Object[]  System.Array
```

As you see this is an array and `Select-String` works on file or on strings.

So the must intuitive way is what [@Lieven Keersmaekers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732154/powershell-select-string-matches-nothing-despite-trying-everything-in-tfm#comment105613774_59732154) said in the comment:

```
Get-windowsfeature | ? {$_.Name -match 'TIFF'}
```

In case of an example with `Get-Alias`:

```
Get-Alias | ? {$_.DisplayName -match "Time"}
```

Output:

```
CommandType     Name                    Version    Source
-----------     ----                    -------    ------
Alias           gtz -> Get-TimeZone     3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
Alias           stz -> Set-TimeZone     3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management
```

As you can see I took `DisplayName`. This is because `Name` only have `gtz` / `stz` but I want to search the text next to `->`.

To display all fields you have acces to you can print it with (as mention from [@Lieven Keersmaekers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732154/powershell-select-string-matches-nothing-despite-trying-everything-in-tfm#comment105613858_59732154) in the comments):

```
(Get-Alias)[0] | fl *
```

or in your case:

```
(Get-WindowsFeature)[0] | fl *
```

## Select-String

In case of using `Select-String` there are two ways which is also used in the reference page mention above.

As mention above by [@Lieven Keersmaekers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59732154/powershell-select-string-matches-nothing-despite-trying-everything-in-tfm#comment105614156_59732154) you can pipe it into a String like:

```
(Get-WindowsFeature | Out-String) -split "\r\n" | Select-String TIFF
```

Another way is to print it into a file and then use Select-String on the file:

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Out-File -FilePath .\Windows_Feature.txt
Select-String -Path .\Windows_Feature.txt -Pattern "TIFF"
```

As a remark don't forget: You may see it as a String but for PowerShell it's an Object and therefore it's not possible to use `Select-String` on it.

Comment: Actually what I misunderstood was the nature of the output from Get-. "|sls" (unless I've still misunderstood) is directly equivalent to "|grep" on Linux and "|findstr" in cmd.exe. The output from Get- is a bunch of objects which can't be grepped, but is converted to text when it hits the screen (or a file, as in my original solution). That's why |sls doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was finding this solve of problems me, too.

```
Get-WindowsFeature | Select-String "Web-Server"
```

not match.

But I found out this solution.

```
PS C:> Get-WindowsFeature | Out-String -Stream | Select-String "Web-Server

[X] Web サーバー (IIS)                                      Web-Server                     Installed
```

"Out-String -Stream" means return as strings.

I tried your pattern.

```
PS C:> Get-WindowsFeature | Out-String -Stream | Select-String "TIFF"

[ ] Windows TIFF IFilter                                Windows-TIFF-IFilter           Available
```

P.S.
I'm studying English, so I'm sorry for my poor English.
2020/10/21(Wed)